# jquery marginTop not working properly

Tags: jquery, css, centering

I'm trying to vertically center text of an unknown height within a div of a known height. I've tried the css `display: table-cell` option, and it didn't work so I'm using jQuery to detect the height and then apply a top margin, if necessary, in order to accomplish the centering - which works when something needs to be adjusted, but then doesn't work to readjust it to have a top margin of zero.

This is my function:

```
function change_trend(){
            trend_text = $('#trends_holder img:eq(' + item_count + ')').attr('data-content');
            $('.trend_text').text(trend_text);
            var trendMargin = $('.trends_scroller').height() - $('.trend_text').innerHeight();
            $('.trend_text').css('marginTop',trendMargin);
}
```

The variable trendMargin is always either zero or twelve. If it's zero, initially, everything is set properly. Then if it is twelve, it sets the top margin appropriately. But then when I get to the next item with a marginTop of zero, it doesn't pop things back up into place where they were. How can I vertically align this stuff? It really doesn't seem like vertical centering should be this hard...

Comment: Can you make an example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)? also is `.trend_text` a block-level element? (`div`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <p> Some text here <br> Some more text here. </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div { 
    line-height:300px; 
}

p { 
    line-height:1em; 
    display:inline-block;        
    width:100%; 
}
```

To set the height of the DIV you use `line-height` instead of `height`. Then, on the child (the container for the text), you set `line-height` back to "normal", and also set `display:inline-block` (this is necessary).

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/5qXMj/1/

Comment: oddly, while this works in JS Fiddle, it does not work if I implement it in my code. Single line examples work, but items with two lines or more just align to the top of the div. Not sure why. But that's a great tip. I will try to implement it in other projects.

Comment: @mheavers You can use Chrome's developer tools to examine what CSS styles are applied to your elements. That way you should be able to figure out the issue easily.

Answer (score 1):

try using 'margin-top' instead of 'marginTop'

Answer (score 0):

```html
<table><tr><td>
    <p>I wont tell anyone if you dont. Inline CSS for extra points.</p>
</td></tr></table>
```